# Unable to decrypt an encrypted password using Jasypt with Spring 2.5.6

Tags: spring, jasypt

I have not been able to make Jasypt work with Spring 2.5.6 to decrypt an encrypted password from the properties file. I do not see any error in the logs either.

I found [one example](https://github.com/nkumarclm/spring-jasypt) of someone using Jasypt with Spring 2.5.6. When I try running this program, I am getting Exception in thread "main" org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException.

If anyone has been able to successfully use Jasypt with Spring 2.5.6, please post the code.

**pom.xml:**

```
    <!-- Spring framework -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasypt-spring2</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

**Spring-datasource.xml:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:encryption="http://www.jasypt.org/schema/encryption"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="environmentVariablesConfiguration"
      class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
    <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />
    <property name="password" value="APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD" />
</bean>

<bean id="configurationEncryptor"
      class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
    <property name="config" ref="environmentVariablesConfiguration" />
</bean>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.jasypt.spring2.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <constructor-arg ref="configurationEncryptor" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:properties/application.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="myClass" class="com.springjasypt.customer.MyClass">
    <property name="username" value="${my.class.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${my.class.password}" />
</bean>
```

**application.properties**

```
my.class.password=ENC(piW7egF06tLgj3Dkji5U+sEmmdMjPMvA)
my.class.username=superman
```

Command used to encrypt password:

```
java -cp C:\reci\apps\tools\mavenpro\org\jasypt\jasypt\1.9.2\jasypt-1.9.2.jar org.jasypt.intf.cli.JasyptPBEStringEncryptionCLI password=APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD algorithm=PBEWITHMD5ANDDES input=secretpassword*123*
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Question has been updated with details. This is the exact code and is similar to the one in the github link posted above. If anyone is able to successfully run this in Spring 2.5.6 (and Spring 3 too), please post how you made it work. The code is really same as what's in the official documentation here: http://www.jasypt.org/spring2.html